# javascript ajax post words which contains & symbol and decode in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, url

i m trying to send ajax post which contains '&'.

```
search.php?region=Middle%20East%20&%20Africa&city=&language=
```

but it return 'Middle East' only  in php side

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'search.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { region: 'Middle East & Africa', city: '', language: '' },
    success: function(result) {
        // ...        
    } 
});
```

If not you could manually URL encode the value using the [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function:

```
var region = encodeURIComponent('Middle East & Africa');
// TODO: send the encoded value
```

Comment: @reju, you don't need to decode anything in PHP. If you properly URL encode the request in PHP simply read the value from the POST collection.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `&` character in a URL, you must first URL encode it. PHP has a function for doing this called [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), which can help. To make the above string work, it should look like:

```
search.php?region=Middle%20East%20%26%20Africa&city=&language=
```

Where the `&` becomes `%26`. Here's the code I wrote to find this:

```
<?php

print urlencode('&');

?>
```